# Rails upgrade from 3.2.2.5 to 4.0.0.12 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upgrade Rails from version 3.2.22.5 to version 4.0.12. Unfortunately, without success so far. It seems that the problem is Simple form, but upgrading to newer versions also doesn't change much. The application is not written by me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I've tried different versions of Simple Form gem but no success so far.

My gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.10'
gem 'rails', '4.0.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg', '0.21'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'nazca', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'polish'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.3'
gem "nokogiri", "1.5.11"
gem "rails_autolink"

gem "capistrano"
gem "capistrano-ext"
gem "capistrano_colors"
gem "rvm-capistrano", require: false

gem "therubyracer"
gem 'cells', '~> 3.11', '>= 3.11.3'

gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "koala"
gem "awesome_print"

gem 'airbrake'

gem 'ransack', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'kaminari-bootstrap'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails4_upgrade', github: 'alindeman/rails4_upgrade'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'letter_opener', "1.1.0"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'phantomjs'

  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-passenger'
  gem 'guard-pow'
  gem "spork", '~> 1.0.0.rc'
  gem 'spork-rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem "rb-fsevent"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'test-unit'



gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem "fog", "~> 1.29.0"
gem "figaro"
gem "rollbar"
```

Here's the error I'm seeing :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.12) was resolved to 4.0.12, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.0.12)

    simple_form (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.3) was resolved to 2.1.3, which depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.12)

    kaminari-bootstrap was resolved to 0.1.3, which depends on
      rails

    nazca (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0)

    rails_autolink was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      rails (> 3.1)

    spork-rails (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
```

EDIT : 
After changing simple form gem to version 3.1 and trying to bundle I see the error :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    cells (~> 3.11, >= 3.11.3) was resolved to 3.11.3, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

    rails (= 4.0.12) was resolved to 4.0.12, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.0.12)

    ransack (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.1) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

    simple_form (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.12) was resolved to 4.0.12, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.0.12)

    ransack (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.1) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 4.0.12) was resolved to 4.0.12, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.0.12)

    ransack (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.1) was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.2)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.9.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "capistrano":
  In Gemfile:
    capistrano

    capistrano-ext was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
      capistrano (>= 1.0.0)

    rvm-capistrano was resolved to 1.5.6, which depends on
      capistrano (~> 2.15.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "kaminari":
  In Gemfile:
    kaminari

    kaminari-bootstrap was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (= 1.5.11)

    capybara was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)

    fog (~> 1.29.0) was resolved to 1.29.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.12)

    kaminari-bootstrap was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
      rails

    nazca (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0)

    rails_autolink was resolved to 1.1.6, which depends on
      rails (> 3.1)

    spork-rails (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.12) was resolved to 4.0.12, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.12)

    sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) was resolved to 3.2.3, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0.beta)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby (~> 2.2.10.0)

    capybara was resolved to 3.15.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3.0)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try deleting your `Gemfile.lock` and then doing `bundle update`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately both bundle update and bundle update rails showing errors.

Comment: The problem here is pretty straight forward - your gemfile lists a version of simpleform that is not compatble with Rails 4. "but upgrading to newer versions also doesn't change much" - be more specific. What exactly did you try and what was the result?

Comment: SimpleForm 3.5.1 depends on ActionPack '> 4', '< 5.2' and ActionModel '> 4', '< 5.2' and should be compatible with Rails 4. You can check this yourself by looking at the [releases on Rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form/versions/3.5.1).

Comment: Hi max ! Thank you for your input. I've tried simple_form version 3.1 (I've edited my question to show the error I'm receiving when trying to bundle)

Comment: This is basically just the dependency hell that occurs when updating Rails. You just have to keep working down the list until you have a bundle that works. This is not really something where Stackoverflow is really that useful as its more just a series of tedius steps and not really a fit for the Q&A format.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Seems like it take a moment to make this upgrade. Thank you for your help!